# How would i make my enemy tower stop for a certain period of time before attacking again in a tower defense game without stopping the whole thing

Tags: python, pygame

I would just like to know how I can do this, the reason why there are 2 towers is because I made the 2nd one go on top of the first one and go invisible so it can have a bigger collision rectangle. I want the tower to wait a bit before attacking again and i do not know how to do this without pausing the entire game, i dont want the whole game to stop just the tower to stop attacking.

```
class Tower:
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        self.image = pygame.image.load( "goku.png" ).convert_alpha()
        self.image = pygame.transform.smoothscale( self.image, ( width, height  ) )
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = ( x, y )

    def get_rect( self ):
        """ Get a copy of the rect, in PyGame style """
        return self.rect.copy()


    

class Tower2:
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        self.image = pygame.image.load( "invis.png" )
        self.image = pygame.transform.smoothscale( self.image, ( width, height  ) )
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = ( x, y )

    def get_rect( self ):
        """ Get a copy of the rect, in PyGame style """
        return self.rect.copy()

class Enemy:
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        self.dead = False
        self.dir = 4
        self.movement = [(810, 100, 2), (810, 350, 4), (620, 350, 8), (620, 275, 4), (410, 275, 2), (410, 350, 4), (298, 350, 2), (298, 450, 4), (80, 450, 8), (80, 350, 4)]
        self.image = pygame.image.load( "saibaman1.png" ).convert_alpha()
        self.image = pygame.transform.smoothscale( self.image, ( width, height ) )
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.topleft = ( x, y )
        self.health = 500

    def move(self): 
        if self.dir == 8:
            self.rect.centery -= 1
        if self.dir == 4:
            self.rect.centerx -= 1
        if self.dir == 6:
            self.rect.centerx += 1
        if self.dir == 2:
             self.rect.centery += 1

    def update(self):
        for pos in self.movement:
            if self.rect.center == (pos[0], pos[1]):
                self.dir = pos[2]

    def color(self, colorid):
        return COLORS[colorid]

    def die( self, action=True ):
        self.dead = action

    def isDead( self ):
        return self.dead

    def collidesWith( self, other_rect ):
        """ Return true, if other_rect overlaps my rect """
        return self.rect.colliderect( other_rect )

    def get_rect( self ):
        """ Get a copy of the rect, in PyGame style """
        return self.rect.copy()

def button_tower(x, y, width, height, mouse, click, image, action = None):
    if x+width > mouse[0] > x and y+height > mouse[1] > y:
        if click[0] == 1 and action != None:
            MainWindow.action_box = action

def text_objects(text, font):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, WHITE)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()

 def button_text(msg, x, y, width, height, mouselse, mouseover, action = None, Text = True):
     mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
     click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

    if x+width > mouse[0] > x and y+height > mouse[1] > y:
        pygame.draw.rect(MainWindow.Gamewindow, mouseover,(x,y,width,height))
        if click[0] == 1 and action != None:
            action()
        else:
             pygame.draw.rect(MainWindow.Gamewindow, mouselse,(x,y,width,height))

    smallText = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf", 20)
    textSurf, textRect = text_objects(msg, smallText)
    textRect.center = ((x+(width/2)), (y+(height/2)))
    MainWindow.Gamewindow.blit(textSurf, textRect)

 class Main:

    def __init__(self, width = WIDTH+100, height = HEIGHT + 100):
        pygame.display.set_caption('DBZ Tower Defense')
        self.startwave = False
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.Gamewindow = pygame.display.set_mode((self.width, self.height))
        # Load images
        self.light_image_map1 = pygame.image.load( "Kami_lookout.png" ).convert_alpha() 
        self.light_image_map1 = pygame.transform.smoothscale( 
        self.light_image_map1, ( width, height ) )
        self.background_rectangle = self.light_image_map1.get_rect()
        self.background_rectangle.topleft = (0,0)


    def wave(self):
        self.startwave = True

    def Intro(self):
        while True:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    sys.exit()

            self.Gamewindow.fill(BLACK)
            largeText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 30)
            TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("simple tower defense game", largeText)
            TextRect = (100, 100)
            self.Gamewindow.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

            button_text("New game", 100, 200, 400, 50, GREEN, LGREEN, MainWindow.MainLoop)
            button_text("Continue", 100, 300, 400, 50, RED, LRED)
            button_text("Exit", 100, 400, 400, 50, BLUE, LBLUE, quit)
            pygame.display.update()


    def MainLoop(self):
        self.enemy = []
        self.tower = []
        self.action_box = None

        self.startwave = True   # Don't have button code, force start

        while True:
            Mainclock.tick(60)
        
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    sys.exit()
                elif ( event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP ):
                    # create a tower where the mouse was clicked
                    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
                    self.tower.append( Tower( mouse[0], mouse[1], 64, 64 ) )
                    self.tower.append( Tower2( mouse[0], mouse[1], 150, 150 ) )
            
            if self.startwave == True and len(self.enemy)==0:
                self.wave(10, 20, 8) 
                self.startwave = False
        
            for i in range( len( self.enemy ) - 1, -1, -1):   # note: loop backwards
                self.enemy[i].update()
                self.enemy[i].move()
                if ( self.enemy[i].rect.left <= 0 ):
                    del( self.enemy[i] )
        
            self.Gamewindow.fill(CYAN)
            self.Gamewindow.blit(self.light_image_map1, self.background_rectangle)
            #button_tower(800, 0, 50, 50, self.mouse, self.click, fantower_image, tower)

             if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0] == 1 and self.action_box != None:
                rectangle30 = pygame.Rect(self.mouse[0]-15, self.mouse[1]-15, 30, 30)
                self.Gamewindow.blit(action_box_image, rectangle30)
             elif self.action_box != None:
                self.action_box()
                self.action_box = None

            for object_enemy in self.enemy:
                self.Gamewindow.blit(object_enemy.image, object_enemy.rect)
            for object_tower in self.tower:
                self.Gamewindow.blit(object_tower.image, object_tower.rect)

            button_text("Start next wave", 0, 600, WIDTH, 100, PURPLE, LPURPLE, MainWindow.wave)
            ll = 0
        
            for tower in self.tower:
                for enemy in self.enemy:
                    if ( enemy.collidesWith( tower.get_rect() ) ):
                        # Make enemy dead
                        print("COLLIDES WITH TOWER")
                        #ll = ll + 1
                        #if ll > 2:
                        if enemy.health != 0:
                             enemy.health = enemy.health - 1
                        else: enemy.die()
                            #ll = 0
                        pp = pygame.time.get_ticks()
                        print(pp)
                    
                    
                    
                        
                    
        
            for i in range( len( self.enemy ) - 1, -1, -1):   # note: loop backwards
                if ( self.enemy[i].isDead() ):
                    del( self.enemy[i] )

            pygame.display.update()

    def wave( self, quantity, size, distance):    # <<-- Made member function of MainWindow
        global saiba
        hh = True
        for i in range(quantity):
            saiba = Enemy(800 + (distance + size)*i, 100- size/2, size, size)
            self.enemy.append(saiba)
```

Comment: It sounds like you need a state machine which can be switched between attacking and paused states.

Comment: Please try and focus the question to a specific issue. Your question is rather generic, and the code shown only contains class and function definitions, but none of that is actually used (e.g., there are no instances of `Tower` or `Tower2` used in the code). Please try and create a [mcve]. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask .

Comment: Sorry i have tried to fix it up a  bit hopefully its better now

Comment: `pygame` has class [pygame.time](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html) which you can use to get current time and compare with some other time in every loop (ie. `current_time < tower.start_delay + tower.delay`) and skip attacking. And every tower should have own variables for this. Eventually this can be use with `state machine`

Comment: You could probably change your `Tower` and `Tower2` to just pass the image as a parameter to the constructor.  Then you only need one piece of code for both objects.

Answer (score 1):

You could modify your `Tower` objects to include a "cooldown timer".

```
class Tower:
    COOLDOWN = 1200  # milliseconds between operations

    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        # ...     
        self.next_attack_time = 0
    

    def canAttack( self ):
        """ Has the attack cooldown-period expired """
        time_now = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        if ( time_now > self.next_attack_time ):
            return True
        else:
            return False
        
    def attack( self, opponent ):
        """ The tower is attacking the opponent """
        if ( self.canAttack() ):
            self.next_attack_time = pygame.time.get_ticks() + Tower.COOLDOWN
            ### TODO: Whatever needs to be done for an attack
            ### Maybe create and return a projectile, change the Tower image, etc.
            return True  # New projectile, whatever
        else:
            return False  # Cooldown is still running; no attack
```

Using these two new functions, `Tower.canAttack()` and `Tower.attack()` it's possible to have the tower keep track of its "cooldown", and use this to manage when the next attack can happen.

This method does not need to use "sleeps".  This is because we're using the system millisecond clock ( `pygame.time.get_ticks()` ) and simply checking whether the "time now" is more than some timestamp we set in the past.

I'm not sure how the attacking should work, but I imagine it creates some new projectile object, returning it when making a new shot is a valid operation (in terms of cooldown).

Comment: The way the attacking system works is in the main class and mainloop of the program i have a colliderect that checks if the enemy health is 0 and if its not then it attacks theres no projectile or shot it just deals the damage so how would i implement this in  a way so that i could stop the attacks of the tower the code actually check if the enemy.collideswith( tower.get_rect() ). If you could clarify this a bit that would be very very helpful thank you

Comment: @omzy54 - The code could just check the result of `a_tower.attack()` is `True` during the collision-check.  So *if-it-collides* and *attack-ok* then continue with the attacking sub-routine.  Otherwise don't do the attacking code.